# Flink elasticsearch connector fails with exception unknown setting [bulk.flush.max.size.mb]

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-flink

The Flink 1.5.0 ElasticSearch connector [page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html) has the following code

```
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
config.put("cluster.name", "my-cluster-name");
// This instructs the sink to emit after every element, otherwise they would be buffered
config.put("bulk.flush.max.actions", "1");
```

Seems like the bulk.flush.max.actions is deprecated or removed. I get the following exception as soon as the program starts.

Here is my exact code (slightly modified version of [this file](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-streaming-demo/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataartisans/flink_demo/sinks/ElasticsearchUpsertSink.scala))

```
    @throws[Exception]
      override def open(parameters: Configuration) {
        val config = new util.HashMap[String, String]
        config.put("bulk.flush.max.size.mb", "1")
        config.put("cluster.name", cluster)

        val settings = Settings.builder()
          .put(config)
          .build()

        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
          .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port))


}
```

and this is the exception i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [bulk.flush.max.size.mb] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.executeJobBlocking(MiniCluster.java:625)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.scala:654)
    at org.myorg.quickstart.StreamingKafkaClient$.main(StreamingKafkaClient.scala:63)
    at org.myorg.quickstart.StreamingKafkaClient.main(StreamingKafkaClient.scala)
```

Also, seems like Fink connector does not work with ES 6.x, i had to uninstall and move back to ES 5.x for Flink to ES connectivity to work. I want to use the bulk.flush.max.actions as i am suspecting that events are getting buffered and not getting pushed to ES after a while (or maybe a different problem is happening but thats out of scope of this issue).

I am using Flink 1.5.0 and the relevant excerpt from pom.xml is as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch5_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why do you use bulk.flush.max.size.mb instead of bulk.flush.max.actions ?

Comment: i tried using that as well (in fact that is what i originally used since that is what was used in the Flink documentation), same error.